# gradle fails to load dll's from jar during TestNg tests

Tags: java, dll, jar, gradle

I'm trying to run some testNg tests with gradle. We use a third party library which is a single jar file. It contains some classes, but it also contains some dll files. When I run it from eclipse "run as TestNg" it works well, but when I try to run tests with gradle I get java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError exception. It certainly sees jar itself, since I have classes from this library in a stacktrace. Here is how my task looks like (the prepare task just copies persistance.xml from resources to classes:

```
task runIntegrationTests(type: Test){
  doFirst(){
    tasks.prepareForIntegrationTests.execute()
  }
  useTestNG()

  include '**/*IT.class'    
}
```

Comment: Not solving your problem, but `TaskInternal#execute()` should never be called from user code. Instead use `dependsOn prepareForIntegrationTests` (without the `doFirst`).

Comment: thanks, I'll fix that. I was hoping that this way I enforce that the preparation task will be executed just before the tests. If I use dependsOn I can't control the order in which the tasks will be executed. Am I right?

Comment: You can enforce before, but not just before.